# Xui.js parent object

Tags: javascript, xui

Xui.js doesn't support `.parent()` by itself, though it *can* use `x$(this)[0].parentNode` to access it, however that returns the literal DOM object it seems. Anyone with xui experience mind telling me how I can convert it into a xui object, so that I can then use functions (addClass/removeClass) on it?

Answer (score 0):

You can by extending XUI, try:

```
var extendXUI = {
  parent : function () {
    return x$(this[0].parentNode);
  }
}
xui.extend(extendXUI);
```